# Jquery, trigger click or enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to submit a field with jquery, normally in the page you would click on a submit button or press enter in the field. 
I'm doing this in a chrome script.
Now if I type:

```
$('#myButton').click()
```

In the Console, this actually works fine, but when i call the same code from my script function, it doesn't work. 
I tried also to use this:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 50; 
e.keyCode = 50;
$("#myButotn").trigger(e);
```

but still no results.

To be specific, the button that i'm willing to click has an onClick="submitFunction()"

Comment: Create fiddle, because  $('#myButton').click() ahve to work, and i think that your trouble not in that case

Comment: and btw - you have spelling error in $("#myButotn").trigger(e);

Comment: I know it's strange, but it doesn't work that way..

Comment: Make fiddle with your code - and i fix it

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what fiddle is?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xy1vu3hc/

Comment: Lol, I think @Legendary was hoping you would include all relevant code in your jsfiddle. Where is your HTML?

Comment: The page is not mine, its chatzy.com , i wanted to throw a message in my chat everytime someone type a certain word

Comment: @Sophie ok, i get it - tell more about your aim, i think i can do that

Comment: The part of the event it's done and works fine, it calls my function that should send the message, but as I saied, this one doesnt work

Comment: @Xan I agree that it's a possible duplicate, but surely we can find something that doesn't have a question score of -4?

Comment: @Teepeemm I know, right? We need a canonical question on this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much better way to trigger a click on keypress.

```
$(window).keydown(function (e) {
    if ( e.which === 50 ) {   
         $("#myButton").click();     
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bc7r3vq1/1/

By the way, keycode 50 is the number 2

Comment: I can't call the function, or at least i don't know how, since the function is into the js page, my script in a chrome extension

Comment: No problem! Please try the updated code and demo

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work.. But anyway I think your function presses the button when I press Enter, (or 2 in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Now, i've found a solution, but i'm not sure which one was the problem.
First of all I started using tampermonkeys, from there i used

```
$('#textField').submit();
```

and it worked fine.

I'm going to check now if I had to use this method, or if it was just something related with my extension.

EDIT: It works only if I use tampermonkeys, as they saied..

Comment: Tampermonkey essentially executes the script in the page's context, that's why it works.

Comment: @Xan Yes you are right, I tried it aswell. Now, despite I fixed it using Tampermonkey, if in the future I will do an extension that i'm willing to put in the store, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is the page you work with guaranteed to have its own jQuery? You work only with specific pages, right?

Comment: Mm I've not idea of what I'll do in the future, for now I'm just doing small scripts for my own..
Anyway, I had to include jquery in my script of tampermonkeys otherwise it would throw "$ is not defined" so I'm supposing it was using my jq

Comment: A generic answer is hard. You would need to simulate the event on the DOM level instead of using jQuery events. A concrete answer (some specific page) may have a simpler answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, but why had I to import jquery in my tampermonkey script if it uses the page's one?

Comment: That I'm not sure. I've never had to deal with Tampermonkey engine in detail.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your issue comes from the browser policy preventing your code from faking a user action. Chrome only allows you to fake a user action if its called directly from another user action handler like an actual user click of keydown. Try your code from within a click handler and if it works its because of this policy block.

Comment: Not the problem here. It's just a question of jQuery copy in a content script not triggering events in page's copy of jQuery. That's why it works from the console.

Comment: Hmm ive done this before from a chrome extension content script and faked events did get triggered in the page and handled by the original page code. But only from a user action.